# Collect Different Types of Files for Retrieval (Maybe like Zotero)

Tags: collection-manager

I am collecting files about an investigation. There are pdf's, Word documents, jpegs, png's. I'd like to keep all of these in one place, sorted by date and perhaps type of content, that is, correlated to different aspects of the investigation. I've heard of specialist software for documents (x1, Windows only) and Relativity; is there anything else?

Comment: Zotero comes close. However, there is no viewing pane and items cannot be renamed within the program. Drag and drop is buggy. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, who knows why?